# Unable to upload selected image if number of selected image exceeds 10

Tags: php

I write a code to upload a image in specific location and display a number of uploaded image count. It will work perfectly when I select below 8 images. But this same code does not worked when if I select 10 to 20 images. I really don't have any idea why it would work when selecting minimum number of images and not working if I select a larger number of images. Please find my below code

storeimage.php

```
 <?php
    require_once 'pdoconnectionusingclass.php';
?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Multiple File Ppload with PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="storeimagename.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div>
          <select name="moviename">
          <option value = "">---Select---</option>
          <?php
          try
          {
            $dbobj=new database();
            $dbobj->openconnection();
            $sql='select * from tbl_movie';
            $query=$dbobj->getdata($sql);
            if(isset($query))
            {
                foreach ($query as $row)
                {
                    echo '<option value='.str_replace(' ','_', $row['movie_name']).'>'.$row['movie_name'].'</option>';
                }   
            }
            $dbobj->closeconnection();
          }

          catch(Exception $e)
          {
              echo $e->getMessage();
          }
          ?>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
          </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

storeimagename.php

```
<?php
require_once 'pdoconnectionusingclass.php';
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
$max_file_size =  1048576 *10; //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files


    $total_image=count($_FILES['files']['name']);

    $dbobj=new database();
    $dbobj->openconnection();

    for($i=0;$i<$total_image;$i++)
    {
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$i] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$i] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$i] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
//                    echo $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
//                    echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $path.$name))
                    {
                        $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
                        $gallery.=','.$name;

                    }
            }
        }
    }
    }

    if(count==18)
    {
         $sql='insert into tbl_movie_gallery values((select movie_id from tbl_movie where movie_name='.str_replace('_',' ',$_POST['moviename']).')'.$gallery.');';
         $dbobj->insertdata($sql);
    }

    //unset($_FILES['files']);
    $dbobj->closeconnection();
}
?>
```

Program is terminated when executing this $total_image=count($_FILES['files']['name']); line if i select 10 to 20 files. $total_image displays count as 0. Can any one help what is the problem is here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a setting for the maximum amount of files you can upload at once. The default is 20. You'll need to change this in your `php.ini` file.

The setting you're looking for is `max_file_uploads`

[More information](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads)

Comment: Yes you are right. But why my code is not working if i select 10 or 12 or 13 images from file browser window. Now i am having max_file_uploads as 20 in php.ini file.

Comment: You may also want to check the other settings in php.ini, for example `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`

Comment: Just a note, don't forget to restart your HTTP server after making changes of php.ini configuration

Comment: thank you very much @rjdown. As  rjdown said, after changing post_max_size in php.ini file my code works well.  Thanks a lot.